# Calculate breakpoint distances between 2 vectors

Tags: r, vector, permutation, bioinformatics

I have 2 vectors;

```
a<-c(1,2,4,3,5,6)   
b<-c(1,4,3,2,5,6)
```

The number of break points between a and b is 3 `([1,2]  [2,4]   [3,5])`

The number of break points between b and a is 3 `([1,4]  [2,3]   [2,5])`

I basically want to check whether or not the numbers are next to each other and print them out, so I don't have to do it by hand every time

Comment: Is `a` actually `"123456"` or is it a proper vector like `c(1,2,4,3,5,6)`?

Comment: *"check whether or not the numbers are next to each other "* What does that mean?

Comment: If it's `3, 2` and `2, 3`, is it a breakpoint? I.e., does the order matter?

Comment: @thelatemail yes it's a proper vector thank you for correcting me there.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I want to see if the numbers are next to each other in the other vector.  In vector a 1 and 2 are next to each other but in vector b they are not. That is why [1,2] is a solution

Comment: @Gabriel Please take a look at my solution below. I'm still unsure about what you're after. Perhaps an expected output would help.

Comment: @Julius   so vector b has 3,2 in that order, but it wouldn't matter if it was 2,3. vector a does not have 3 or 2 next to each other anywhere in the vector. I hope that clarifies it!

Comment: @Gabriel, what I meant is a situation with `3, 2` in `a` and `2, 3` in `b`. Is it a breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions. First let

```
a <- c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6)
b <- c(1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5)
```

where note that I switched the last two elements of `b`. Then

```
# Creating a vector of pairs of subsequent elements of x
fun <- function(x) paste(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
BP <- function(x, y) fun(a)[!fun(a) %in% fun(b)]
BP(a, b)
# [1] "1 2" "2 4" "3 5" "5 6"
```

takes into account this order. That is, it includes `5 6` as a breakpoint. Alternatively, if the order doesn't matter and it's only about being next to each other:

```
BP <- function(x, y) fun(a)[!(fun(a) %in% fun(b) | fun(a) %in% fun(rev(b)))]
BP(a, b)
# [1] "1 2" "2 4" "3 5"
```

Then `length(BP(a, b))` gives the distance.

Comment: thank you! this is what I wanted. Can you roughly explain what that code means?

Comment: @Gabriel, as the comment says, `fun` creates a vector of pairs of subsequent elements of `x`; e.g., `fun(c(1,2,3))` would give 1,2 and 2,3. Then, e.g., the first kind of `BP`, simply looks for such pairs of `a` that are not among the pairs of `b` (`!fun(a) %in% fun(b)`) and returns them.